# Trouble Connecting to Wi-Fi Via GUI

Tags: ubuntu, networking, wifi, gui, wpa2

I am having a small issue with my Wi-Fi adapter. It seems that the GUI interface is struggling to connect, so it does not automatically connect when I start the system. In order to connect, I have to open a command-line shell & execute the following command:

```
$ sudo iw dev <device_name> connect <SSID>
```

So the credentials have been stored correctly. It just seems the GUI network manager is having some issues.

I am running a 2007 MacBook Pro with Ubuntu MATE 19.04 x86_64. This is a fresh install.

```
$ lspci
...
0b:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR5418 Wireless Network Adapter [AR5008E 802.11(a)bgn] (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
...

$ lsmod | grep -i ath
ath9k                 151552  0
ath9k_common           36864  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              475136  2 ath9k_common,ath9k
ath                    36864  3 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath9k_hw
mac80211              806912  1 ath9k
cfg80211              671744  4 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath,mac80211
```

**Edit:** I apologize, I did forget to mention that my WiFi uses WPA2 Personal security.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  I don't know too much about WiFi configuration, unfortunately, so I won't be able to answer you myself.  However, I think if you edit your post to make it clearer what the exact question is, you'll be more likely to attract answers.  I *think* it's, "How can I configure the host to connect automatically without the terminal command?" but I'm not sure (and on first reading I completely missed that you could even connect at all).